# Rewriting a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to rewrite a  tag using Javascript. The code looks like this

```
<div id="captcha" style="display: none;">
    [content]
</div>
```

So I am trying to rewrite the entite tag so it removes the styling

```
"style="display:none;"
```

From the tag on pageload. I already have this code, but I cannot seem to get it to work:

```
var divv = document.getElementById("captcha");
divv.innerHTML = divv.innerHTML.replace("style="display: none;", "");
```

Comment: What's wrong with `divv.style.display='';`?

Comment: The `style` attribute is not part of `innerHTML` of `#captcha`, rather it's part of `outerHTML`.

Comment: Your are changing inner information (content) not style of your div block. Try .style instead, more you can read here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Comment: Style is an attribute in your div and not innerHtml

Comment: "removes the styling ... from the tag on pageload." Why not just update the file?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Thanks Nerfair for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.

Here is the good way :

```
document.getElementById("captcha").style.display='';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
document.getElementById("captcha").style.display='';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the innerHTML of the div#capthca, not the attribute called style.

```
var divv = document.getElementById("captcha");
divv.style.display = '';
```

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbx9uuLL/

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
div.attr("style").replace();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
var divv = document.getElementById("captcha");
divv.style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 0):

You've made some common and obvious mistake as well:

```
"style="display: none;"
*      *              *
```

(please note the 3 quote marks!)

you have to use different quote marks, like '', not "" if your content also have ""

For example (theoretically)
'style="display: none;"'